# How can I display my search results in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, httpresponse

When I write city in field and click button, on page has to be that name of city and another. In my case every time name is New York. When I write for example Las Vegas my link is `http://localhost:3000/?query=Las+Vegas&commit=Search`, the data on the page is about New York.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    @params = {
      :access_key => "1dbc1a3aa6b2e76a0c8eda1cba0c9c8b",
      :query => "New York"
    }
    @uri = URI("http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=1dbc1a3aa6b2e76a0c8eda1cba0c9c8b&query=#{@params[:query]}")
    @uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(@params)
    @json = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @api_response = JSON.parse(@json)
    if @params[:query].empty?
      @city = "Enter city"
      @temperature = "(in English)"
    else
      @city = " #{@api_response['location']['name']}"
      @temperature = "#{@api_response['current']['temperature']}°"
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index', :as => 'search'
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="weather">Weather</h1>
  <%= form_with(url: search_path, method: "get", local: true) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search",class: "btn btn-primary") %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="city"> <h1><%= @city %>  <h5><%= @temperature %></h5></h1> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have hardcoded New York in your params.

```
@params = {
      :access_key => "1dbc1a3aa6b2e76a0c8eda1cba0c9c8b",
      :query => "New York"
    }
```

So you need to change this to be something like:

```
@params = {
      :access_key => "1dbc1a3aa6b2e76a0c8eda1cba0c9c8b",
      :query => params[:query]
    }
```